# filter articles for category in Dango

Tags: python, sql, django

Very good, I am doing a personal blog as the first project in the world of web development, which I am developing with django, but I have a problem, the truth is I cannot find a way to filter my articles by categories, I show you my viewed models.

I have seen some examples using foreign keys but that causes me that the articles can only have a single category. I understand that to get the articles by categories I have to do a "fiilter" of categories but I even got there, if someone could guide me I would appreciate it very much

```
class Article(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Titulo')
subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='Máximo 50 carácteres, que no se te olvide' ,verbose_name='subtitulo')
content = RichTextField(verbose_name="Contenido")
image = models.ImageField(default="null", verbose_name="Imagen", upload_to = "media")
user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Usuario", on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Categorias")
create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Creado el")
update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Editado el")

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = ('Articulo')
    verbose_name_plural = ('Articulos')
    ordering = ['id']


class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Nombre")
description = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Descripcion")
create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Creado el")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = ('Categoria')
    verbose_name_plural = ('Categorias')
```

/views:

```
def article(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    categorys = Category.objects.all()
    comments = Comentary.objects.filter(post = article_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have seen some examples using foreign keys but that causes me that the articles can only have a single category.

Indeed, by using a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), you can link an article to *multiple* categories, and a category can contain *multiple* articles.

Since you define first the `Article`, you can not refer to the `Category` later in the file, since at that moment `Category` is not defined *yet*. You can make use of a string literal to do this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # …
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', verbose_name='Categorias')
    # …

class Category(models.Model):
    # …
```

Now we can retrieve the `Category`s of a given `Article` with:

```
my_article.categories.all()
```

or we can obtain all `Article`s that at least have a given category with:

```
Article.objects.filter(categories=my_category)
```

If you want thus to render categories for the given article, you can work with:

```
def article(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    categorys = article.categories.all()
    comments = Comentary.objects.filter(post = article_id)
```

you can also make a view to see a `Category` with its related `Article`s with:

```
def category(request, category_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    articles = category.article_set.all()
    # …
```